# waiting for new page data to be loaded before redirecting?

Tags: javascript, html

The heading is self explanatory, let me give you an example:

I have the main page with a search bar and after a user hits go, instead of immediately redirecting to the search page can we wait on the main page until the data for the search page to be loaded and **then** redirect?

maybe something like this:

```
let URL="/search-page"

when_ready(URL,()=>{
  window.location.href = URL;
});
```

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)?

Comment: @JeremyThille isn't that only for when the current window loads? can you use it to wait for a new window data to be received?

Comment: I think thats possible in single page applications where all pages are under control of a main JavaScript routine (such as in AngularJS or Vue.js). Then, the calling page couls wait for an event and then 'redirect' - which is not a real redirect of the browser but a switch of the view.

Comment: @Nechoj I was hoping for a vanilla JavaScript answer but I'll look into it

Comment: Development of single page applications is a whole new topic and not achieved by menas of some script pattern, see e.g. video on page `https://v3.vuejs.org/`

Answer (score 0):

You can check condition like the status code of the response is 200 then redirect to another page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: could you elaborate with some code?